# How do I get my game to access my Content folder after I published my C# game?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I made a game using XNA Game Studio 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010.

The solution has a project which is the game and a project which is the content.

In this content folder I have located all the .png files and such.

The game works fine when I run it from VS.

But when I try to publish my game using ClickOnce, it installs correctly but it won't run.

The error it gives me an error saying that it can't access the content folder.

Full error:

> Gebeurtenisnaam van probleem:   CLR20r3
>
> Probleemhandtekening 01:    myGame.exe
>
> Probleemhandtekening 02:    1.0.0.0
>
> Probleemhandtekening 03:    52e540d8
>
> Probleemhandtekening 04:    mscorlib
>
> Probleemhandtekening 05:    4.0.0.0
>
> Probleemhandtekening 06:    517a1c71
>
> Probleemhandtekening 07:    3fde
>
> Probleemhandtekening 08:    105
>
> Probleemhandtekening 09:    System.IO.DirectoryNotFound
>
> Versie van besturingssysteem:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>
> Landinstelling-id:  1043
>
> Aanvullende informatie 1:   0a9e
>
> Aanvullende informatie 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Aanvullende informatie 3:   0a9e
>
> Aanvullende informatie 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789